# Flutter column auto height by parent row

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I try use Column auto height but still not working.

Example

- Card

  - Row

    - Expanded(flex:4)

      - NetworkImage (this image has height 120)
    - Expanded(flex: 4)

      - Container

        - Column (this is column what I need)

So I found solution that I have to use Expanded widget so I tried it and got exception

- Card

  - Row

    - Expanded(flex: 4)

      - NetworkImage (this image has height 120)
    - Expanded(flex: 4)

      - Container

        - Expanded

          - Column (this is column what I need)

Expanded widgets must be placed directly inside Flex widgets.
I/flutter (14383): Expanded(no depth, flex: 1, dirty) has a Flex ancestor, but there are other widgets between them:
I/flutter (14383): - Expanded(flex: 4) (this is a different Expanded than the one with the problem)
I/flutter (14383): These widgets cannot come between a Expanded and its Flex.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be because of the fact that you are adding one of those `Expanded` widgets to a `Container`.

> An Expanded widget must be a descendant of a Row, Column, or Flex, and
>   the path from the Expanded widget to its enclosing Row, Column, or
>   Flex must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other
>   kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

Replacing the container with a Column should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, but I used Container for use paddings, I will try put Container inside Expanded. I have one more question and what is different between Flexible vs Expanded

Comment: Unlike Expanded, Flexible does not require the child to fill the available space : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html